length function in c++
I think the output of this code should be 8 because the length function should not calculate null char '\0'.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string test1 = "abcdefghi";
    test1[2] = '\0';
    cout << test1.length()<< endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

I think the output should be 8 because I change byte 2 to a null value. But the output is 9. Why?

because length function does not calculate null char - Who told you that?

std::string can contain embedded \0, because it stores its length instead of computing it every time. Some other parts of the standard library (primarily those coming from C) stop at \0, but not std::string.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size
It returns the number of CharT elements, including null terminators

Apart from what others have pointed out, why would you expect 8? I could understand expecting 2 because you "terminated" (well, actually not) the string at index 2. What would be the use case for a skip-zeros length calculation?

"abcdefghi" is a char[10] (including \0), test1.length() is 9...

The null character is not "nothing", it is a character.

I think it's more of a misconception that \0 doesn't count when determining the length instead of not knowing that a std::string can have embedded nulls. Just like the previous comment said a null character is an actual character. It's not "nothing"

Related question with basically the same setup but does not look at length(): Are std::string with null-character possible?

@Friedrich  because the length of this s="\0\0\0" is equal 0 so I  expected that the output should be 8

@molbdnilo because the length of this s="\0\0\0" is equal 0 so I expected that the output should be 8

"\0\0\0" is a string literal. The assignment  s="\0\0\0" will have to treat it as a c-string otherwise what would the length be if it doesn't terminate with \0

@Mikel91 "\0\0\0" is not a std::string, it's a string literal which is basically a const char*`

@Mikel91 I think the output should be 8 because I change byte 2 to a null value. But the output is 9. Why? -- You see that the length is exactly the same as what you started with before you changed the character.   That should have given you the clue as to what is happening -- if you change a byte, all you did was change that byte -- you didn't do anything else.

demo

@Mikel91 I think the output of this code should be 8 -- Also, your expectation of what "length" should do is "strange", or maybe "not expected".  You expected length to count all of the non-null characters?  If so, that function goes far and beyond what "length" suggests.  If you want to count the number of non-null characters in a std::string, it requires you to call a function (or write a function) that scans the string and counts up the non-null characters.

@Mikel91 "because the length of this s="\0\0\0" is equal 0" -- Experimenting is good, but why did you stop there? Why did you not try s = "ab\0defghi" (to match what you are creating in your example code)? Or if you're feeling creative, maybe try "\0\1\2" as an example where not all of the characters are null? (It's kind of weak to conclude that the non-null characters are counted when there are no non-null characters to count.)

Why did you not try s = "ab\0defghi" Here is that: https://ideone.com/7yqiR5

@drescherjm it should be using namespace std::literals; s = "ab\0defghi"s; see demo I've provided above. JaMiT statement is simply inaccurate.

@MarekR I just made an example out of the comment that was right above my comment.

@MarekR "JaMiT statement is simply inaccurate." -- Which statement?

C++ string objects support embedded null bytes, unlike C strings (char*). If you set a byte at any position to 0 (aka '\0'), it will not remove it or terminate the string at any position. The string will just contain a null byte where you put it.
To truncate a string at position 2 (setting its length to 2):
test1.resize(2);

To delete just one byte at position 2 (the length becomes smaller by 1):
test1.erase(2, 1);


Ugh, had no idea string's test1.erase(2); did this. I think I'd rather test1.resize(2); for consistency with containers.

Yes, that syntax sucks. No idea why I came up with it.

Nitpicking, but C strings do support null bytes anywhere, it's the C standard library that doesn't.

@Yksisarvinen Doesn't a "C-string" by definition end at a null byte?

@HolyBlackCat No that's just a very widely used convention. (But yeah it is surprising if it doesn't).

@PepijnKramer The C standard defines "string" as a null-terminated one (7.1.1 Definitions of terms in C11). I agree that a string doesn't have to be null-terminated, but when people say "C-string" they usually mean a null-terminated one. IMO.

You are right. It is specified ;) Astring is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character. I learned something today. ;)

Alright, I meant char[], didn't know that C standard defines "string". char array can store any values, including \0, and some C standard library functions accept number of elements together with array (e.g., strncpy).
